# How optimize stratified random sampling in r with 10000 repetitions

Tags: r, data.table, simulation, resampling

I need a function that uses **stratified random sampling** to *repeatedly* (10000 times)sample from my data for **varying sample sizes**, calculate the mean and standard deviations and return a coefficient of variation for every sample size. the sample size ranges from 3 to 30.
I have written this so far but it is too slow. I need help to make it run *faster* since I am running this part of the code many times.
The data frame dt1 has about 900 observations
K_level has 6 levels

Thank you

```
samp <- function(nn){
  dt1 <- as.data.table(dt1)
  dt2 <- replicate(10000, dt1[, .SD[sample(x = .N, size = nn)], by = K_level], 
          simplify =  FALSE) %>% 
  data.table::rbindlist() %>% 
  .[,.(avg=mean(Bunch_weight), Sd = sd(Bunch_weight)),.(Trt)] %>% 
  .[, cvs:= Sd/avg] 
  dt3 <-  data.table::transpose(dt2)
  colnames(dt3) <- as.character(dt3[1,])
  dt4 <- dt3 %>% .[-c(1:3),] %>% .[, sample:= paste0(nn,"mts")]
  return(dt4)
}
# use the function
zzz <- c(3:30)
dat5 <- map_df(.x = c(3:30), .f = samp)  

my data
Block Trt Matno Cycle Date.harvested Girth0 Girth100 Hands Fingers Bunch_weight    Variety K_level
  1:    B1  T2     6     1     2020-03-05      1        1     1       1            5     NFUUKA      0K
  2:    B1  T6     2     1     2020-03-05      2        2     2       1            9     KIBUZI    150K
  3:    B1  T6     3     1     2020-03-09      3        3     1       2            5     NFUUKA    150K
  4:    B1  T6    24     1     2020-02-28      4        4     2       1            9     KIBUZI    150K
  5:    B1  T6    29     1     2020-03-03      5        5     3       3           14     NFUUKA    150K
 ---                                                                                                   
780:    B3  T9    12     1     2020-05-22      4        4     4       4            8     NFUUKA      0K
781:    B3 T10    10     1     2020-05-25    145       47     5       5           17     NFUUKA      0K
782:    B3 T11    14     1     2020-05-16     27       88     4       4           13 MBWAZIRUME     75K
783:    B3 T14    25     1     2020-05-24     39      119     4       3           14    KISANSA    150K
784:    B3 T14    34     1     2020-05-17     27       28     5       3           15  NAKITEMBE    150K

expected output
 T9                T1                T6               T14               T13                T7               T15
1: 0.359418301512993 0.259396490785659 0.352112606549899 0.270098407993612  0.33255344147661 0.246297750226982 0.290376334651094
2:  0.36336940312546 0.260242995748078 0.347937570013322  0.26993786977025 0.327215546595358 0.247590005787063 0.290659581719395
                  T8                T3                T4               T18               T17               T10               T11
1: 0.203153174250691  0.31104051648633 0.308308574237779 0.352809537743834 0.380933443587759 0.345214551318585 0.265386556956891
2:  0.20127162406244 0.311140161227165 0.303006865683816 0.350513136037457  0.37965782184899 0.342121680883066  0.26389652807615
                  T5               T12               T16                T2 Sample
1: 0.424907358546752 0.262966077905422 0.292193075443918 0.366954072154349      3mts
2: 0.413114236465515 0.264733595838422 0.296869773806402  0.36574334095091      4mts
```

Comment: you can just calculate the statistics inside the ```replicate``` function instead of using binding it.. you don't need to store the data.frame. thats my point

Comment: @StupidWolf how does that work inside replicate to make it faster than the pipes?

Comment: Ok hmmm this part ```replicate(10000, dt1[, .SD[sample(x = .N,  .. ```, you replicate your sampling 10000 times and bind the list, so if nn is 3, you are sampling it effectively 10000 * nn * (maybe number of groups)

Comment: If I get your code correctly, so it doesn't quite make sense for me. I would write it as ```replicate(10000,dt1[, .SD[sample(x = )..] %>% calculate mean,cv) ```

Comment: and lastly, actually, you only need to sample the vector ```Bunch_weight```, if you subset your data.frame or data.table to the need columns, you will avoid the inferno of binding data.frame, speeding up your function

Comment: I tried with `sw <- replicate(10000,dt1[, .SD[sample(x = .N, size = 3)], by = K_level] %>% mean(Bunch_weight))` sw has only NAs. did miss something?

Comment: At least try some tags or not to setDTthreads() to see if it helps. I have doubts about performant chaining with %>%. I never do it. I chain dt with ][ .  If I have to, I reference the previous dt with .SD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your code just shuffled round a bit. I think it produces the same output, but it's hard to tell as the randomness is done in a different order so resetting the random seed doesn't help. It ought to be substantially (>10 times) faster.

```
samp2 <- function(nn){
  dt1 <- as.data.table(dt1)
  dt2 <- dt1[, .SD[as.vector(replicate(10000, sample(.N, nn)))], by = K_level, 
    .SDcols = c('Trt', 'Bunch_weight')][, 
      .(avg=mean(Bunch_weight), Sd = sd(Bunch_weight)), by = .(Trt)]
  dt2[, cvs:= Sd/avg]
  dt3 <-  data.table::transpose(dt2)
  colnames(dt3) <- as.character(dt3[1,])
  dt4 <- dt3 %>% .[-c(1:3),] %>% .[, sample:= paste0(nn,"mts")]
  return(dt4[])
}
```

Comment: thank you @pseudospin. this is much faster. I see that you are chaining the data.table way but is that all. why is this faster?  i really need to understand what made my code slow or why is yours faster

Comment: I doubt the chaining is the issue at all - either way is probably fine. The difference here is the grouping by `K_level`. Yours does it 10,000 times and then rbinds the resulting whole datatables together. Mine does it once and then selects 10,000 lots of rows all at once for each `K_level`.